# Unity has disappeared from lightdm after updating gnome-shell

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome, lightdm

This morning I ran `sudo apt-get upgrade` and it prompted me to update `gnome-shell`. I never really use the gnome desktop environment, but I figured I might as well keep it up-to-date.

After restarting my laptop I noticed that lightdm had selected gnome as the desktop environment and when I tried to switch it back to unity I noticed that unity was missing from the list.

Unity is still installed somewhere, but it seems to have been removed from `/usr/share/xsessions/`. I've tried running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity`, but it doesn't seem to have changed anything.

I've checked [this answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100926/no-unity-session-after-update) and it suggests that the solution is to remove gnome-shell. I'm a bit hesitant to do this though, if I remove gnome-shell and unity doesn't come back I'll be left without any desktop environment.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to turn the Unity plugin back on. The problem is this is a pain in the bottom because you've now got no graphical method to do this. So:

Install the jibby you'll need to configure the settings by running this:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

2.Then run it by doing this:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
ccsm
```

There will be CompizConfig Settings Manager screen (or open it from menu).

```
Find the Unity plugin. Enable it.
```

Everything should spring into life but if it doesn't, you might have to restart.

Source:[Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Comment: Do I need to uninstall gnome-shell first? I tried following those instructions without uninstalling but unity still doesn't show in lightdm after restarting. If I load compizconfig-settings-manager it now says that the unity plugin is enabled though.

Comment: No, you dont need to uninstall gnome-sheell ..have you tried resinstalling gnome session...................................... `sudo apt-get --reinstall install gnome-session`.

Comment: Of course reboot the machine after it..